# Can't install ROS package listed on index from either apt or rosdep

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to download [this package](https://index.ros.org/p/grpc/github-CogRob-catkin_grpc/) called "grpc" for compiling Protobuf messages. However, on my Noetic installation, running `sudo apt install ros-noetic-grpc` (or even `sudo apt list ros-noetic-g*`) turns up nothing. Other Noetic packages like e.g.:

```
ros-noetic-grid-map-ros/focal 1.6.4-1focal.20220512.131357 amd64
ros-noetic-grid-map-rviz-plugin-dbgsym/focal 1.6.4-1focal.20220512.132257 amd64
ros-noetic-grid-map-rviz-plugin/focal 1.6.4-1focal.20220512.132257 amd64
ros-noetic-grid-map-sdf-dbgsym/focal 1.6.4-1focal.20220221.112002 amd64
ros-noetic-grid-map-sdf/focal 1.6.4-1focal.20220221.112002 amd64
```

are showing up, but not the one I want. I also tried `rosdep install grpc` to "cannot find all required resources." I'm on an x64 20.04 machine, and my ros-latest.list has `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal main`. Would anyone know why I can't find this package, or if they're able to see it on other machines?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402741/can%27t-install-ros-package-listed-on-index-from-either-apt-or-rosdep/) by [nabeelsherazi](https://answers.ros.org/users/106898/nabeelsherazi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-23**:
Looks like [it's not actually available in the repositories right now](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_default.html?q=grpc).

Why? I don't know. You'd have to ask the maintainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn Thank you for the link, this is a good resource! I reached out to the maintainer as you suggested and found out that its because it was just published recently, and a "sync" hasn't happened yet for the package to be available on apt. Appreciate it!

---

Originally posted by [nabeelsherazi](https://answers.ros.org/users/106898/nabeelsherazi/) with karma: 16 on 2022-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-27**:
Issue on the tracker: [CogRob/catkin_grpc#40](https://github.com/CogRob/catkin_grpc/issues/40).